# Access to datalist event inside another databound control & finding controls inside nested datalist

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net, datalist

I have a DataList inside another DataList. I want to access the child DataList "dlQuestion" events, ItemDataBound event. Also, I'm tring to find the control LableControl "lblQuestion" in the child datalist. How do I do that? Here's the mark-up:

```
<asp:DataList ID="dlSection" runat="server" Width="100%">
   <ItemTemplate>
       <div>
         <asp:Label ID="lblSection" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Section") %>'></asp:Label>
         <asp:HiddenField ID="hfSectionId" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("SectionId") %>' />
        </div>
        <asp:DataList ID="dlQuestion" runat="server"  >
        <ItemTemplate>
           <asp:Label ID="lblQuestion" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Question") %>'></asp:Label></td>
           <asp:HiddenField ID="hfQuestionId" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("QuestionId") %>' />
        </ItemTemplate>
       </asp:DataList>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to handle `ItemDataBound` event of the dlQuestion DataList and get lblQuestion Label in that event handler:

Markup:

```
<asp:DataList ID="dlSection" runat="server" Width="100%">
     <ItemTemplate>
          <div>
               <asp:Label ID="lblSection" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Section") %>'></asp:Label>
               <asp:HiddenField ID="hfSectionId" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("SectionId") %>' />
          </div>
          <asp:DataList ID="dlQuestion" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="dlQuestion_ItemDataBound">
               <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblQuestion" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Question") %>'></asp:Label></td>
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="hfQuestionId" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("QuestionId") %>' />
               </ItemTemplate>
          </asp:DataList>
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

Code-behind:

```
protected void dlQuestion_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        var lblQuestion = e.Item.FindControl("lblQuestion") as Label;
        if (lblQuestion != null)
        {
            lblQuestion.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I did that except that my function "Private" instead of "Protected". Thank you this.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way finding label control in child datalist...

```
 //here I am finding item(DataList) of child Datalist

 DataList dlSubChild = (DataList)childItem.FindControl("dlSubChild");
 foreach (DataListItem subChildItem in dlSubChild.Items)
 {

       //here I am finding item(TextBox) of sub child Datalist
       TextBox txtName = (TextBox)subChildItem.FindControl("txtName");



      //set literal(litName) text

     litName.Text = string.Format("{0}{1}", "Welcome ", txtName.Text);

}
```

i hope it will helps you ...